# Filtrar resultados por las relaciones Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy haciendo un filtrador y, quiero poder filtrar también por las variaciones de un producto. Esas variaciones son por ejemplo, color, talla, genero. Ya he filtrado por categorias, subcategorias, pero esto me resulto más facil ya que guardo esos datos en la misma tabla, pero las variaciones no y no se como hacer.

El AJAX donde según los checkboxes que marco hace una petición al controlador y devuelvo la respuesta en php.

```
public function filtros(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->only("categoria", "subcategoria", "marca", "search", 'genero');
        
        $filtrador = Product::with('variaciones')
                ->join('categories', 'products.categoria', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategoria', '=', 'subcategories.id')
                ->join('marcas', 'products.proveedor', '=', 'marcas.id')
                ->select('products.*', 'categories.name as nameCategoria', 'subcategories.name as nameSubcategoria', 'marcas.empresa as proveedor');

                //verificamos que exista y contenga almenos 1 dato
                if(isset($data["categoria"]) && count($data["categoria"])){
                    $filtrador = $filtrador->whereIn('products.categoria', $data["categoria"]);
                }

                //verificamos que exista y contenga almenos 1 dato
                if(isset($data["subcategoria"]) && count($data["subcategoria"])){
                    $filtrador = $filtrador->whereIn('products.subcategoria', $data["subcategoria"]);
                }

                if(isset($data["marca"]) && count($data["marca"])){
                    $filtrador = $filtrador->whereIn('products.proveedor', $data["marca"]);
                }

                if(isset($data["genero"]) && count($data["genero"])){
                    $variat=  DB::table('variations')->whereIn('valor', $data["genero"])->get();
                    //dd($variat);
                    foreach($variat as $filt){
                        $filtrador = $filtrador->whereIn('products.id', $filt->product_id);
                    }   
                }

                if($request->ajax()){
                    $filtrador = $filtrador->where('products.name', 'LIKE','%'.$request->search."%");
                }

                //solo como ejemplo, en caso de obtener el ultimo
                $last = "";
                if($last){
                $filtrador = $filtrador->latest('id');
                }else{
                //o devolver la lista
                $filtrador = $filtrador->paginate(6);
                }
                
                $filtradorHtml = "";
                

                foreach($filtrador->items() as $pro){
                    $filtradorHtml .= "<div class=\"col-4\">
                    <div class=\"cardProduct\">
                      <div>
                        <div style=\"position: relative\">";
                          if ($pro->foto == null){
                            $filtradorHtml .= "<img src=\"images/no-foto.jpg\"  class=\"imgProduct\">";
                          }else{
                            $filtradorHtml .= "<img src=\"$pro->foto\"  class=\"imgProduct\">";  
                          }
          
                    $filtradorHtml .= " 
                        <div class=\"etiqueta3estados\">";
                            if ($pro->estado == 1){
                                $filtradorHtml .= "<span class=\"publicado\">Publicado</span>"; 
                            }elseif ($pro->estado == 2){   
                                $filtradorHtml .= "<span class=\"noPubli\">No publicado</span>";
                            }elseif ($pro->estado == 3){
                                $filtradorHtml .= " <span class=\"borrador\">Borrador</span>";
                            }
                    $filtradorHtml .= " 
                        </div>
                          <div class=\"posicionPapelera\" id=\"posicionPapelera\">
                            <a href=\"\"><i class=\"far fa-edit eyeProduct\"></i></a>
                            <a href=\"\"><i class=\"far fa-trash-alt eyeProduct\"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>        
                        <div class=\"mgTop9\">
                          <div class=\"marcaDiv\">
                             $pro->proveedor
                            <span class=\"pull-right refeProduct\"> $pro->referencia </span>
                          </div>
                          
                          <div class=\"productTitle\"> $pro->name </div>
                          <div class=\"cardpProduct\"> $pro->descripcion</div>
                          <div class=\"dropdown-divider margb4\"></div>
                          <div class=\"row targCate\">
                              <div class=\"col-6\">
                                  <h5>Categoría</h5>
                                  <span> $pro->nameCategoria </span>
                              </div>
                              <div class=\"col-6\">
                                  <h5>Subcategoria</h5>
                                  <span> $pro->nameSubcategoria </span>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class=\"lasOpt\">
                                <div>
                                    <h5>Genero:</h5>
                                    <span>";
                                    $dash   = '';
                                    $string = ''; 
                                    foreach($pro->variaciones as $varia){
                                        if ($varia->variant == 'genero'){
                                            $string= $dash.$varia->valor;    
                                            $dash = ', ';
                                            $filtradorHtml .= "$string";
                                        }
                                    }    
                        $filtradorHtml .= 
                                    "</span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h5>Tallas:</h5>
                                    <span style=\"text-transform: uppercase;\">";
                                    $dash   = '';
                                    $string = ''; 
                                    foreach($pro->variaciones as $varia){
                                        if ($varia->variant == 'tallas'){
                                            $string= $dash.$varia->valor;    
                                            $dash = ', ';
                                            $filtradorHtml .= "$string";
                                        }
                                    }    
                        $filtradorHtml .= 
                                    "</span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h5 style=\"margin-right: 5px;\">Colores:</h5>";
                                    foreach($pro->variaciones as $varia){
                                        if ($varia->variant == 'colores'){
                                            $query =  DB::table('terminos')->where('slug', $varia->valor)->get();
                                            foreach($query as $pr){
                                                $string = $pr->color;
                                            }
                                            $filtradorHtml .= "<span class=\"cuadrosColorPrueba\" style=\"background: $string;\"></span>";
                                        }
                                        
                                    }    
                        $filtradorHtml .= 
                                "</div>
                           </div>
                          <div class=\"dropdown-divider margb4\"></div>
                          <a href=\"\" class=\"btn btnGuardar corrigeBtNverproducto\">Ver producto</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>";
                }
                
                if($filtradorHtml == '') { $filtradorHtml = 'No hay productos, o el mensaje que quieras que aparezca'; }

                $filtradorHtml .= "<div class=\"container center margBlog1 pull-right\" style=\"padding: 0;\">";
                $filtradorHtml .= $filtrador->links(); 
                $filtradorHtml .= "</div>";
                

        return $filtradorHtml;
    }
```

Aunque se que no esta bien esta mezclado los INNER con el with, pero ahora me gustaria saber como puedo comparar lo que marco con la tabla variaciones, para filtrar por esos datos.

El valor que mando de la vista al AJAX sobre el genero, es ejemplo("hombre") mando un slug para poder compararlo con la tabla variations.

**Tabla productos**

```
+----+------------+----------+---------------+
| id |    name    |categoria | subcategoria  |    
+----+------------+----------+---------------+
| 1  | sudadera   |     2    |       1       |
| 2  | camiseta   |     5    |       3       |
| 3  | pantalon   |     2    |       4       |
| 4  | deportivas |     9    |       5       |   
+----+------------+----------+---------------+
```

**Tabla variations**

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| id | product_id | variant  | valor     |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1          | genero   | hombre    |
| 2  | 1          | color    | negro     |
| 3  | 1          | color    | rojo      |
| 4  | 1          | color    | blanco    |   
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Lo que tiene que pasar es que si marco el checkbox hombre, tiene que sacar los productos que tengas ese valor, pero no se como hacer la query, llevo horas pensando sin éxito.

**Edición**

Estoy probando de este modo, pero sin éxito:

```
if(isset($data["genero"]) && count($data["genero"])){
   $variat=  DB::table('variations')->whereIn('valor', $data["genero"])->get();
   //dd($variat);
   foreach($variat as $filt){
     $filtrador = $filtrador->whereIn('products.id', $filt->product_id);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una manera de hacerlo es creando una consulta `DISTINCT` a tu tabla `variations` para la columna `product_id`.

Esa misma funcionará como una subconsulta para los productos.

El SQL resultante deberá ser similar al siguiente.

```sql
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT producto_id FROM variations WHERE variant = 'genero' AND valor = 'hombre'
);
```

El código PHP:

```php
$filtrador = $filtrador->whereIn(
    'id',
    static function ($query) use ($data) {
        $query
            ->select(['product_id'])
            ->from((new Variation)->getTable())
            ->where('valor', $data["genero"]);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta @Baruch Spinoza , me devuelve este error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::andWhere()`

Comment: De todos modos creo que la linea de `->where('variant', 'genero')` sobras, es decir que bastaria con un where, pero claro como lo asocio `$filtrador = $filtrador->` @Baruch Spinoza

Comment: Si, una disculpa, parece que el método andwhere no existe, creo que lo he confundido con otro framework. Ya edité mi respuesta.

Comment: pero como te comentaba lo he añadido a `$filtrador = Product::select()->whereIn(` pero me devuelve `Collection::paginate does not exist.` @Baruch Spinoza y el primer where no es necesario

Comment: Si le quito el `get` funciona pero no me saca algunos datos

Comment: Es que me esta anulando la primer consulta, por eso no me salen algunos datos que saco de ella, alguna solución @Baruch Spinoza

Comment: Supuse que agregarías esas condiciones a tu variable $filtrador pero lo dejé como un query general para que sirviera también para otras personas. Ya corregí la respuesta para que se adapte únicamente a tu caso.

Comment: Woowwww funciona estupendo, muchisimas gracias! ahí van 50 puntos extra!!